# Java DatagramSocket throws a SocketTimeoutException after a few runs

Tags: java, udp, socketexception

I am writting a Java application that reads game server information. That's all it does, it runs in a loop doing the same thing.

The problem is that at first it works great, I get a response. After some(not a constant number) times it starts throwing the SocketTimeoutException.

This is the method I use for querying a SAMP server.

```
    private ByteBuffer sendQuery(char opcode) throws IOException {

    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(11);
    bf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bf.put("SAMP".getBytes("US-ASCII"));
    bf.put(encodeIP(getIp()));
    bf.putShort((short)getPort());
    bf.put((byte)opcode);
    Logger.getLogger().log("Request to " + this.getAddress().getHostString() + ":"+ByteConvert.bytesToHexString(bf.array()));

    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bf.array(), bf.capacity(), getAddress().getAddress(), getPort());
    getSocket().send(packet);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, getAddress().getAddress(), getPort());
    getSocket().receive(packet);
    if(packet.getLength() > 4096)
        Logger.getLogger().log("Large packet received from " + this.getIp() + " :"+packet.getLength());
    bf = ByteBuffer.allocate(packet.getLength());
    bf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    bf.put(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
    bf.flip();
    return bf;
}
```

`encodeIP` method:

```
private static byte[] encodeIP(String s) throws IOException {
    String[] ip = s.split("\\.");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[ip.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < ip.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(ip[i]);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

The protocol is documented [here](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism).

Other games have the same issue but currently i'm investigating SAMP as its protocol seems to be the simplest.

The application is running on Linux, Debian 7.0. I tried disabling the firewall completely.

Comment: Does your getSocket() method return a previously created socket, or is it constantly creating a new one?

Comment: It always return the same socket. I create a socket at the constructor to be used and `getSocket()` returns it.

Answer (score 0):

So the reply got lost, or didn't get sent. You have to cope with either. UDP is an unreliable protocol, and code contains bugs, or unexpected exits.

NB there's no point in initializing the address and port of a `DatagramPacket` you're about to receive into. They will get overwritten by the source address:port of the incoming packet.

Comment: I aware of packet loss. But currently if the server times out, I try it 5 more times and all of these times there's a socket timeout(all of this occurs only after some time). Can the packet loss be that high? And thanks for the tip :)

Comment: If the reply packet is lost, it is lost. Retrying won't make it magically reappear. What you should be retrying is the entire request/response cycle, ensuring that your requests are idempotent of course.

Comment: That's what I meant. I try sending a request and then receiving it. I try this up to 5 times.